# httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, django, mod-wsgi

Please help I'm new to this and I was trying to learn django but got stuck at this for last 24 hrs

C:\Apache\bin>httpd.exe
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name
, using 10.26.27.30 for ServerName
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

C:\Apache\bin>netstat -ao -p tcp

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             KW-PC:0               LISTENING       4768

PID 4768 is running apache 2.2

Comment: I check services which also had apache 2.4 but was disabled. Anyways I removed it with command: sc delete "Apache2.4"

Comment: reinstalled Apache using Xampp. Again it stopped working while restarting. Then checked error                                 <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/mysite>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
<Directory>                                                         forgot to close Directory -> i.e.</Directory>                                                    But Apache still not working so ticked of Svc in Xampp control panel and it started working